# Show that if $f\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is surjective then it is also bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, induction

> Show by **induction** that if $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is surjective then it is also bijective.

**My approach:**

Base case $n=1$:

$f:\{1\}\to\{1\}$ is trivially bijective.

Induction hypothesis for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ is surjective then it is also bijective.

Induction step $n\to n+1$:

Let's consider the surjective function $f:\{1,\dots,n+1\}\to\{1,\dots,n+1\}$. If $f^{-1}(n+1)$ contains only one element, i.e. $f^{-1}(n+1)=:k$, then $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ with

$$\begin{align*}
g(x):=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\neq k,\\ f(n+1),&x=k\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

is surjective and we can apply the induction hypothesis. Hence, $g$ is bijective. Consequently,
$$\begin{align*}
f(x):=\begin{cases}g(x),&x\neq k,\\ n+1,&x=k,\\ f(n+1),&x=n+1\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
is bijective.

If $f^{-1}(n+1)$ contains more than one element, WLOG we denote those elements by $f^{-1}(n+1)=:\{1,\dots,k\}$, then $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ with

$$\begin{align*}
g(x):=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\notin \{1,\dots,k\},\\ f(n+1),&x\in\{1,\dots,k\}\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
is surjective and we can apply the induction hypothesis. Hence, $g$ is bijective. Consequently,
$$\begin{align*}
f(x):=\begin{cases}g(x),&x\notin \{1,\dots,k\},\\ n+1,&x\in \{1,\dots,k\},\\ f(n+1),&x=n+1\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
is bijective.

Is this correct? It seems a bit odd to conclude bijectivity as we have $f(n+1)$ for all $x\in\{1,\dots,k\}$.

---

**EDIT:**

As $f:\{1,\dots,n+1\}\to\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ is surjective we know that $f^{-1}(n+1)\neq\emptyset$ and define $S:=f^{-1}(n+1)$. We consider two cases:

**If $n+1\notin S$**, then we define $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ by
$$\begin{align*}
g(x):=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\notin S,\\ f(n+1),&x\in S.\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
We take an arbitrary $y\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and by surjectivity of $f$ there exists a $x\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

1.) Either $x=n+1$ so that any $z\in S$ yields $g(z)=f(n+1)=y$,

2.) or $x<n+1$ and because of $y< n+1$ we know that $x\notin S$ which yields $g(x)=f(x)=y$.

Consequentially, $g$ is surjective and we can apply the induction hypothesis so that $g$ must be bijective. This means that $S$ contains exactly one element which we denote by $s$. Now we can represent $f:\{1,\dots,n+1\}\to\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ equivalently by
$$\begin{align*}
f(x):=\begin{cases}g(x),&x\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{s\}\\ n+1,&x=s\\f(n+1),&x=n+1.\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
We know that $g$ is bijective so $f(n+1)\neq g(x)$ for all $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{s\}$. Also $n+1\neq f(n+1)$ by assumption and $g(x)\neq n+1$ for all $x\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ because $g$ maps to $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Bearing this in mind we check for injectivity of $f$. If $f(x)=f(y)$ then this could only be possible if $x=y=s$, $x=y=n+1$ or $x,y\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. But as $g$ is bijective the third possibility also delivers $x=y$. So $f$ is injective and hence bijective.

**Now we assume $n+1\in S$** and define $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ by
$$\begin{align*}
g(x):=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\notin S,\\ 1,&x\in S.\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Let's take an arbitrary $y\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, then by surjectivity of $f$ there exists a $x\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ such that $f(x)=y$. As $y\leq n$ the corresponding $x$ satisfies $x\notin S$ so that $f(x)=g(x)=y$. Hence, $g$ is bijective by induction hypothesis. This means, that $S\cap\{1,\dots,n\}=\emptyset$ because otherwise $g$ couldn't be injective. So $S$ contains only one element, namely $n+1$.  Now we can represent $f:\{1,\dots,n+1\}\to\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ equivalently by
$$\begin{align*}
f(x):=\begin{cases}g(x),&x\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{n+1\}\\ n+1,&x=n+1.\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
In this case we directly see that $f$ must be injective. Hence, $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it follows from bijectivity of $g$ that $f$ is bijective? You may technically be right, but at this point in the proof you're arguing under an absurd assumption, so the usual way to conclude would be to reach a contradiction. In this case it would be absurd for $g$ to be bijective, since it is evidently not injective, so you have a contradiction from that.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, maybe I should simply add that bijectivity of $g$ implies that $\{1,\dots,k\}$ can only contain **one** element. Then it becomes clearer that $f$ is bijective. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Indeed that would work - but again, since the "case" you're in in that part of the proof is "If $f^{-1}(n+1)$ contains more than one element..." I think it's a bit clearer/more coherent to finish that case by reaching a contradiction - ie argue that you must actually have been in the first case all along. You can also re-structure the proof a bit and completely remove the "If $f^{-1}(n+1)$ contains only one element" case and just argue that $k$ must be $1$, which would work.

Comment: I don't know exactly how much detail you're supposed give but usually if you're
proving something like this I'd expect a little more justification for why
everything is injective/surjective that you claim. Also WLOG assuming that the
preimage of $n+1$ is $\{1,\dotsc,k\}$ is a pretty big assumption - I think
it's almost as hard to prove as the statement in question. Maybe see if you
can write the proof without making this assumption. This is probably overkill -
I'm being quite nitpicky and you've done a good job already and you're clearly
thinking carefully about rigour.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, yes I think the first case in my attempt is superflous. I have edited my proof.

Comment: Your proof looks very good to me now. Both answers below appear to assume facts about well-definedness of cardinalities and the relationship between cardinalities of subsets, which I think is not intended (nor is eg the pigeonhole principle), since this fact or one like it is how you prove those other facts in the first place. Your proof looks almost exactly like how I'd write it. I might have added a few more words about why $g$ is surjective, and a nice trick is compose with a transposition like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795551/473276), so you can assume $f(n + 1) = n + 1$.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought the previous definition of $g$ seemed alright. It doesn't make sense for $n + 1$ to be an output of $g$, because its codomain is supposed to be $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I think I have to take the case $f(n+1)=n+1$ separately into consideration. Otheriwse it could be that $g$ is not well defined.

Comment: Yes - I suppose the easiest way to fix it is to instead define $g(x) = 1$ for $x \in S$ (the point being that the value of $g$ basically doesn't matter for $x \in S$). Good catch though, and sorry for not spotting that myself. I'd still say it's worth writing down why $g$ is surjective to clarify this a bit!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I had to think a bit longer about how to fix the issue. I have put another edit. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$\{1,2,\dots,n\}\supseteq f^{-1}(\{1,2,\dots,n\})=\bigcup_{k=1}^nf^{-1}(\{k\})$$

and note that

1. the $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ are disjoint
2. $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ has at least one element (because $f$ is surjective)

Now, taking cardinalities

$$n=|\{1,2,\dots,n\}|\ge |f^{-1}(\{1,2,\dots,n\})|=\sum_{k=1}^n|f^{-1}(\{k\})|\ge\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n$$
which implies that $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ has precisely one element for any $k$. This is the very definition of injectivity: if $f(a)=f(b)=k$ then
$$a,b\in f^{-1}(\{k\})$$
so it must be the case $a=b$ is the only element of $f^{-1}(\{k\})$

Comment: Not by induction (my bad). But could be useful anyways

Comment: I guess that this is pretty much the standard proof; but one remark: it relies on the fact that it is known that the cardinality is well defined, i.e. unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is correct, but I'll provide another proof here. We shall prove the generalisation of the question: "Show that if $f:\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}\to\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ is surjective, then it is also bijective, where $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ are distinct". Let $P(n)$ denote this statement for the case of $n$.

Base case: $P(1)$ is clearly true.

Induction hypothesis: $P(1), P(2), \dots, P(k)$ are all true, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}+$.

Inductive step: We claim that $P(k+1)$ is true.

First if there exists $i$ such that $f(a_i)=a_i$, then we can "remove" $a_i$ and we are left with $k$ elements. Since $P(k)$ is true, we know that $P(k+1)$ is true.

Now suppose $\forall i, f(a_i)\neq a_i$. Define the sequence $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{k+1}$ by $b_0=a_1$ and $b_i=f(b_{i-1})$ for $i\geq1$. Since $b_i\in\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$, the sequence must be periodic. Let $m>0$ be the first element such that $b_m=b_0$.

First note that $m<n$ because, since $f(x)$ is surjective, $\{b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}\}\subseteq\{a_1, a_2, \dots a_n\}$, so $m\leq n-1\implies m<n$. Second note that since $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ is distinct, $\{b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}\}$ is distinct. Hence, we can "remove" $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{m-1}$ and we are left with $k+1-m$ elements. Since $P(k+1-m)$ is true, we know that $P(k+1)$ is true.

This completes the induction.